# Will the newest API push orders to my Store's POS terminal if I add an order on a website?

Tags: square-connect, square

I had previously worked with the Square API and it had a downfall of not working all too well with websites.  In particular, if I made an order online, there was no way to "push" that order to the guys working so they could see it.  I had to develop a second app that showed the online orders, so they were looking at two screen and could easily miss one.

My question is simply this: can I put in an order online, and force a reciept to print (ideal) and/or have it at least show up with the other orders on the Square app for my cooks, or do they have to navigate to another screen or find it buried somehwere?

Please let me know if you require more info on my question - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, order pushing is now available within Square's APIs. If you:

1. Use [CreateOrder](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/create-order) endpoint, with `fulfillments` parameter
2. Pay for the order (no way to pay for the order in person at this time - it must be paid before it is sent to the POS app)

Then the order will show up in both the Square POS application (if you're using a tablet), and the Square dashboard. On the Square POS application, a modal will pop-up asking you to view the new order. For full documentation around this, please take a look at the [Order-Ahead App Usecase](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/orders-api/order-ahead-usecase) in Square's docs. They will all live under the "Orders" tab within the POS app, just for clarification.